# Как верно истолковать этот код?

Tags: jquery

У меня была проблема, что при выводе изображений через fancybox показывалось 14 изображений, хотя у меня их 6. Задача была подключить к fancybox только элементы, которые НЕ клонированы. Owl карусель добавляет к клонированным элементам специальный класс - cloned. Решение нашел

```js
$().fancybox({
  selector : '.gallery .owl-item:not(.cloned) a'
});
```

Потом нашел код jquery, который будет подключать fancybox к клонированным элементам, при переключении.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.gallery .owl-item.cloned a', function(e) {
  var $slides = $(this)
    .parent()
    .siblings('.owl-item:not(.cloned)');

  $slides
    .eq( ( $(this).attr("data-index") || 0) % $slides.length )
    .find('a')
    .trigger("click.fb-start", { $trigger: $(this) });

  return false;
});
```

Но дело в том, что местами не понимаю, что как работает и поэтому прошу вашей помощи разобраться с последним кодом.
Сам сайт tempeswo.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]